# jQuery function not defined error. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is given my code function is not written inside document ready function. When I am clicking on this link it giving me error function is not defined How can I resolve this error. Please help me and thanks in advance and sorry for my grammatical mistake.

HTML:

```
<a id="10" onclick="deletereport(this.id)" class="delete" style="color:red"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
```

jQuery:

```
function deletereport($id){
  alert($id);
}
```

Comment: Have you included **JQuery** lib in your page?

Comment: @mariocatch, I asked that because he has included **$**, and this will work once JQuery lib is included.

Comment: Yes, I included jQuery lib everything working fine except this function please help me.

Comment: Can you show how your error looks like in console? Also, more html!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it needs: 1/ the *entire* error message quoted; 2/ to *show us* that you're including the jquery library by *showing us a **complete** [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a id="10" onclick="deletereport(this.id)" href="javascript:void(0);">
<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </a>
    <script>
    function deletereport($id){
      alert($id);
    }
    </script>
```

Please check this code, added `href="javascript:void(0);`